# Get keyCharValue with KeyCode and Modifiers

Tags: java

I use the library [JNativeHook](http://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/) which allows to listen to every event from my keyboard.

It sends events [NativeKeyEvent](http://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/source/browse/trunk/src/org/jnativehook/keyboard/NativeKeyEvent.java?spec=svn214&r=214) but unlike the KeyEvent class, its method getKeyChar doesn't use the modifiers !

That's the reason why I would like to know if there is an easy way to obtain a char value with its keycode and its modifiers.

For instance :

- keycode=65, modifiers=null : 'a'
- keycode=65, modifiers=MAJ  : 'A'

Thanks !

Comment: I don't think there's any way in simple Java. The keyboard layout to character mappings happen in the OS.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Take look at [KeyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) class in java. It has methods [getKeyText(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyText%28int%29) and [getKeyModifiersText(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyModifiersText%28int%29).

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I need a method which takes both !

Comment: @user1196936: can you elaborate your need/problem?

Comment: Done, i've just eddited my post :)